# toggle Drawer from BottomTab

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I would like to toggle Drawer from BottomTab... so as soon as i press tab icon i want Drawer to toggle. I have tried a different solutions but didnt have any success. Please help. This is my code:

```
App.js

export default function App() {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <BottomTab/>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}
```

```
BottomTab.js:

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function BottomTab() {

    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Tab.Navigator>
                <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={DrawerTab} style={styles} />
            </Tab.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

```
Drawer.js:

const ScreenComponent = ()=>{
    return null
}

const ScreenComponentTwo = ()=>{
    return null
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function DrawerTab() {
    return (

        <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
            <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={ScreenComponent}/>
            <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={ScreenComponentTwo}/>
        </Drawer.Navigator>

    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tabBarButton` prop to use your custom element for the tab bar button. This way you'll have a direct control of what happens when this item is pressed and you can simply call `navigation.openDrawer();`

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator#tabbarbutton

or you can use `tabpress` event to override default behaviour and call `navigation.openDrawer();` from there.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator#tabpress

Comment: Thank you for your answer! i have been trying with TabBarButton, and TabPress... but no luck... can you show me how would you do it?